# How to use NSOperationQueue to download audio files from server one by one

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have an array containing audio file url's. I want to fetch audio files from server using these url's in background mode. I have heard that i can achieve this with NSOperationQueue. My query is

1)How can i achieve this.

2)How can i get call back on single operation completion/failure

3)How can i get call back after completion of the whole process.

I need these call backs to keep track of downlaod process so that i can update my database about the download status of files. So, in case any internet connection loss i can download the remaning files again.

Any idea will be helpful as i am new to NSOperationQueue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) has all that you need (callback blocks for success / failure, puttings requests in NSOperationQueue). In your case probably `AFHttpClient` and its `enqueueHTTPRequestOperation` method will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(download:) object:aAudio];
[queue addOperation:operation];//added code
[operation release];
```

now do stuff what u want in method `download`. as per [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) set `[queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1]` for one by one.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, but i have done it with the help of ASIHTTPRequest library. Easy to implement & gives whatever me what i want. But later i discovered that it is deprecated. So googled & found some usefull libraries for this to achive. One of  it is mentioned by Michał Ciuba in above comments. Following can be used for such operations

1) AFNetworking

2) LRResty

3) RestKit

4) AWS SDK for iOS

5) ShareKit

6) NSURLRequest/NSURLConnection

For more details [link](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D)